# Efficiently create a JSON per row of a tibble

Tags: r, json, tidyverse

I am trying to create a column in my tibble with a combination of specific fields' values.  Here's an example that works for small *n*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tibble)

fields_to_compile = c("brand", "cyl")

df <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  mutate(brand = factor(str_sub(car, 1, 4))) %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl))

for(r in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[r,'combo'] <- toJSON(df[r,fields_to_compile])
}
```

Which returns this:
[image]

However, this is painfully slow for a dataset the size of the one I'm actually working with.  Is there a more efficient approach to the problem?

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but if performance is a big concern this could be re-written in `python` using `pandas` with fairly similar syntax and amount of code, but a huge performance boost because the relevant transformations will be run using compiled C code in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to vectorize this and avoid the loop.

Does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tibble)

fields_to_compile = c("brand", "cyl")

df <- mtcars %>%
   rownames_to_column("car") %>%
   mutate(brand = factor(str_sub(car, 1, 4))) %>%
   mutate(cyl = factor(cyl))
 
 df %>% rowwise(car) %>% mutate(combo= toJSON( across(fields_to_compile)))
 
 # or maybe
 df %>% rowwise(car) %>% summarize(combo= toJSON( across(fields_to_compile)))

df %>% rowwise(car) %>% mutate(combo= toJSON( across(fields_to_compile)))
# A tibble: 32 x 14
# Rowwise:  car
   car                 mpg cyl    disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb brand combo                       
   <chr>             <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <json>                      
 1 Mazda RX4          21   6      160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 Mazd  [{"brand":"Mazd","cyl":"6"}]
 2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21   6      160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 Mazd  [{"brand":"Mazd","cyl":"6"}]
 3 Datsun 710         22.8 4      108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 Dats  [{"brand":"Dats","cyl":"4"}]
 4 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4 6      258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 Horn  [{"brand":"Horn","cyl":"6"}]
 5 Hornet Sportabout  18.7 8      360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2 Horn  [{"brand":"Horn","cyl":"8"}]
```